# Scripted Data Source using JSON not working with BIRT while working in Java Class

Tags: java, eclipse, json, birt, alfresco

I will talking throw codes line with a few words, In alfresco I need to create a reports using its Workflows APIs that response as JSON, I found the solution for using JSON as a Data Source in this link (this will be good reference to full understand my issue) :

http://www.birt-exchange.org/org/devshare/designing-birt-reports/1053-scripted-data-source-using-json/

I downloaded the source and I understand how its works, and finally I was having a problem "authentication issue" and solved it by editing source file 'JSONParser.java', anyway I have another problem now, I have the following code in Java thats working:

```
package com.actuate.json.test;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.actuate.json.JSONParser;
public class TestJSONParse_OutBound {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            JSONParser theParser = new JSONParser();
            theParser.loadData("http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/workflow-definitions/activiti$CS-Outbound-WFPD:5:403/workflow-instances?state=active&amp;format=json","admin","admin");
            System.out.println("Number of jobs found: " + theParser.getChildCount("data") + "\n");
            for(int i = 0; i < theParser.getChildCount("data"); i++){
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(i + 1) + ")  " + theParser.getValue("data", "description", i));
                System.out.println("\tID: " + theParser.getValue("data", "id", i));
                System.out.println("\tURL: " + theParser.getValue("data", "url", i));
                System.out.println("\tUsername: " + theParser.getValue("data", "initiator/firstName", i));
            }
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }catch(Exception ex){

        }
    }
}
```

Result :

```
Number of jobs found: 2

1)  CS-Outbound-WFPD
    ID: activiti$499
    URL: api/workflow-instances/activiti$499
    Username: Administrator
2)  CS-Outbound-WFPD
    ID: activiti$404
    URL: api/workflow-instances/activiti$404
    Username: Administrator
```

---

BUT In BIRT Report in eclipse IDE no luck 1, in Scripted Data Source I put:

```
count = 0;
controller = new Packages.com.actuate.json.JSONParser();
controller.loadData(params["JSONURL"],params["USERNAME"],params["PASSWORD"]);
totalCount = controller.getChildCount("data");
```

and fetch rows in data set table like :

```
if(count < totalCount){
    row["id"] = controller.getValue("data", "id", count);
    row["url"] = controller.getValue("data", "url", count);

    count++;
    return true;
}
return false
```

But still giving me white page with head titles only, empty cells !!.

To get exception I uploaded it to Alfresco integrated with BIRT, and I got :

```
WARNING: Fail to execute script in function __bm_OPEN(). Source:
------
" + count = 0;
controller = new Packages.com.actuate.json.JSONParser();
controller.loadData(params["JSONURL"],params["USERNAME"],params["PASSWORD"]);
totalCount = controller.getChildCount("data"); + "
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.actuate.json.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="8"]/method[@name="open"]#2)
 Script source: /report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="8"]/method[@name="open"], line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.core.DataException: Fail to execute script in function __bm_OPEN(). Source:
------
" + count = 0;
controller = new Packages.com.actuate.json.JSONParser();
controller.loadData(params["JSONURL"],params["USERNAME"],params["PASSWORD"]);
totalCount = controller.getChildCount("data"); + "
-----
A BIRT exception occurred. See next exception for more information.
Error evaluating Javascript expression. Script engine error: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.actuate.json.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="8"]/method[@name="open"]#2)
 Script source: /report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="8"]/method[@name="open"], line: 0, text:
__bm_OPEN()
    at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.script.JSMethodRunner.runScript(JSMethodRunner.java:147)
.
.
.
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: [JavaPackage com.actuate.json.JSONParser] is not a function, it is object. (/report/data-sources/script-data-source[@id="8"]/method[@name="open"]#2)
.
.
.
```

Really I don't know what the problem is, and how to solve, if anybody have any idea for It, I spent about 1 week on it with no solution ...

Comment: I'd check your classpath, and ensure you only have one copy of each of the jars - my hunch is you may have both old and new copies of at least one and that's confusing it

Comment: @Gagravarr I think all jars is copied, I downloaded "httpcomponents client 4.0" and put all as external jars on eclipse for my project, and copied it to WEB-INF/lib on alfresco (with JSONParser classes as a jar file), I forgot to put them first and I got Class Not Found Exception, but now you see my problem that I got after that ...

Comment: Those steps don't ensure no duplicate jars. I'd double check, especially the com.actuate, birt and rhino jars

Comment: @Gagravarr sorry if is to late, I was in Vacation and hen so busy with another project, just I want to know how I check that ?

Comment: Ask the classloader to give you the class as a resource, then print the URL and check it has come from the jar you expected. [See this](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10006) for an example of looking for where a different jar comes from as a start

Comment: @Gagravarr um, thank you, after i trying to find classes loaded, for some reason , JSONParser class not loaded, alfresco didn't see that.